# revertFunc() is not working

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I've recently updated FullCalendar from v1.6.4 to v2.0.2 and in doing so has caused my `revertFunc()` in my `eventDrop` callback to stop working.

When I try to drop an event in an invalid area it does not return to its original position and I get this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

This is the code I am using:

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc)
            {
                var now = moment().format("HH:mm");

                var eventStart = event.start.format("HH:mm");

                if (eventStart < now)
                {
                    showNotification("red", "Can not place appointments before the current time");
                    revertFunc();
                }
                else...
```

Comment: have you seen this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

Comment: what does eventStart  and now contains?

Comment: check this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/ and do required changes

Comment: @rjdmello I took a look at those links yes, have no idea how I skimmed over the part about the parameters being removed! Thanks, will try and post results.

Comment: @rjdmello Working fine now. Thanks a million!

Answer (score -2):

Check the [documentation of the new version](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/) of `eventDrop`, the parameters order has changed and that is why your code is not working:

```
function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { }
```